# Is there a way to minimally log insert under Always on?

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql, transaction-log, availability-groups, bulk-insert

I have a primary database in `FULL` recovery mode which is part of `Always On` group. Is there a way to minimally log insert operation under `FULL` recovery model?

I have a process that is executed each day and insert few millions of records in a table. While the operations continued the transaction log file size is increased dramatically ( from 1 GB to 40 GB).

As I have read I can used some variations of `INSERT` which are not fully logging the operation but I am concern about the effect of switching the recovery model?

Comment: Thanks but `Minimally logged operations are available only if your database is in bulk-logged or simple recovery mode.` (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070(v=sql.100).aspx) and the database in full recovery mode. I am going to check the batches insert examples either.

Comment: Could anyone tell if the numbers of records inserted matters, or the size of the row? I have 37 millions rows to insert, but I can group them in 147 772 rows if I change the table structure (for example XML and ID). The data will be the same as size (maybe bigger) but the rows will be less.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  Full recovery model is a prerequisite of AlwaysOn Availability groups as per the check list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878487.aspx), and minimally logged operations are only available under Simple or Bulk Logged recovery.

Quote from the [Data Loading Performance Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070(v=SQL.100).aspx):

> Minimally logged operations are available only if your database is in
>   bulk-logged or simple recovery mode.

Re trace flag 610, what that added was the ability to do minimally logged inserts to tables with clustered indexes ( and/or non-clustered indexes ) with data already in them.  This was not previously available.

The thing to bear in mind about minimally logged transactions as that as soon as a transaction log backup contains one of these, you **lose the ability to do point-in-time restore** with that backup.  So hopefully now you understand why these are not available in Full recovery model